# how to create my own qrcode scanner without using third party application?

Tags: android-support-library

I am using zxing library for creating qrcode scanner in my app.But the problem is when I am clicking on scan button it is asking to download third party scanner.But I need an inbuilt Scanner in my app.Please help me out.